# OnCelldouble click in my gridview

Tags: c#, wpf, double-click

I need to double click the cell in my gridview and whenever I click it, it should open a new window to edit the value. However, on my codes, it return to null even if i have a value. I think  the event handler for my gridview is incorrect. Heres is the message "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Here's is my code..

Constructor:

```
grdProducts.AddHandler(GridViewCellBase.CellDoubleClickEvent, 
                       new EventHandler<RadRoutedEventArgs>(OnCellDoubleClick), 
                       true);
```

Click Events:

```
private void OnCellDoubleClick(object sender, RadRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Product product = (sender as Telerik.Windows.Controls.GridViewColumn).DataContext as Product;
    ShowProductWindow(product);

    //MessageBox.Show("test");
}
```

Help me to figure it out.

Comment: Can you show an exact line where you have that exception?

Comment: @JleruOHeP this:

Product product = (sender as Telerik.Windows.Controls.GridViewColumn).DataContext as Product;

Comment: Here is my code snippet for calling the RadWindow:

private void ShowProductWindow(Product product)
{
     if (product != null)
     {
         ProductWindow productWindow = new ProductWindow(product, projectDBContext);
         productWindow.Closed += ProductWindowClosed;
         productWindow.ShowDialog();
     }
}

Comment: Im not sure what will be the sender for the event should I call. I think telerik has another way to call the method..

Answer (score 1):

You have that exception because your sender is not of type `Telerik.Windows.Controls.GridViewColumn`. Probably your sender would be GridViewCell. Try something like this:

```
private void OnCellDoubleClick(object sender, RadRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var cell = e.Source as GridViewCell;
    if (cell == null) return;

    var row = cell.ParentRow as GridViewRow;
    if (row == null) return;

    Product product = row.DataContext as Product;
    ShowProductWindow(product);

    //MessageBox.Show("test");
}
```

Comment: It didnt work. It always return to null even if the cell has a value.

Comment: @Kim Can you check then - what is your sender?

Comment: my sender is RadRoutedEventargs on the cell and it works but the cell still returns to null. I did try my code like this..

Product product = (sender as Telerik.Windows.Controls.GridViewColumn).DataContext as Product;

still, the cell on my grid return to null. I think telerik has a different approach. Im not sure..

Comment: Here is my code snippet on how the radwindow will show up..

Product product = (sender as RadButton).DataContext as Product;
            ShowProductWindow(product);